# Why is there a need to parametrize the contour when we can get the answer using cauchy residue theorem?

Tags: integration, contour-integration, parametrization, cauchy-integral-formula

In the following an integral has been evaluated using Cauchy residue theorem which seems enough. Why is there a need to parametrise the contour to evaluate the same integral i.e. what is the point in this ?

[image]

Comment: Is the integral of interest a contour integral or an integral over the reals?

Comment: Maybe to show a practical example that it gives the same result. That is done in books sometimes.

Comment: Perhaps the next step is taking the limit at $R \to \infty$, since the integral you actually want is not the integral on $C_R$ but the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.  If so, then we would "parameterize the contour" and show the integral on $A_R$ goes to zero.

Comment: 3rd question on the residue theorem... In short, the residue theorem is the statement that if $f$ is meromorphic on a finite rectangle or disk $U$ and $\gamma$ is a simple closed loop contained in $U$ then $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz =2i\pi \sum_{k=1}^K Res(f(z),\alpha_k)$$
where $\alpha_k$ are the finitely many poles of $f$ inside $\gamma$.

Then you can use it to evaluate some integrals $I$ by finding a meromorphic function $f$ and a sequence of closed loops such that $I = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_n}f(z)dz$.